# Axios post method returens 500 error in vue.js + laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-blade

I am using vue.js with axios to post my data.I am trying to calculate total value using v-model and save the value in DB. it returns with connection close 500 Internal Server Error.Here is the error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBRT8.png). I cant echo or dd() the return value. How can I do that? Please Help..................

**My laravel controller code:**

```
public function smvCostAdd(Request $request)
{
    $response = [
        'status' => '',
        'message' => '',
    ];

    $rules = [
        'knittingCost' => 'required',
        'linkingCost' => 'required',
        'tremingCost' => 'required',
        'mendingCost' => 'required',
        'washCost' => 'required',
        'pcqCost' => 'required',
        'ironCost' => 'required',
        'ironCost' => 'required',
        'sewingCost' => 'required',
        'packingCost' => 'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ]);
    }
    $trans_id_d= $request->trans_id_d;


    try {
        $edit_data = BCACost::where('trans_id_d', $trans_id_d);
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $edit_data->KNITTING_C = $request->knittingCost;
        $edit_data->LINKING_C = $request->linkingCost;
        $edit_data->TRIMMING_C = $request->tremingCost;
        $edit_data->MENDING_C = $request->mendingCost;
        $edit_data->WASH_C = $request->washCost;
        $edit_data->PQC_C = $request->pcqCost;
        $edit_data->IRON_C = $request->ironCost;
        $edit_data->SEWING_C = $request->sewingCost;
        $edit_data->PACKING_C = $request->packingCost;
        $edit_data->update();
        DB::commit();
        $response['status'] = "success";
        $response['message'] = 'Data Stored Successfully!';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        $response['status'] = "danger";
        $response['message'] = 'Data Store Failed. Error Code: 101';
    }
    return response()->json($response);

}
```

**Route code in web.php**

```
Route::post('bca/smv-cost-action', 'BCAController@smvCostAdd');
```

**Blade code:**

```
<form id="smv-cost-form">
<input type="hidden" name="trans_id_d" value="36">
<tr id="smvCostAdd" class="">
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="knittingCost" id="knittingCost" v-model.number="knittingCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="knittingCost_error">
            @{{knittingCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" id="linkingCost" name="linkingCost" v-model.number="linkingCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="linkingCost_error">
            @{{linkingCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" id="tremingCost" name="tremingCost" v-model.number="tremingCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="tremingCost_error">
            @{{tremingCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" id="mendingCost" name="mendingCost" v-model.number="mendingCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="mendingCost_error">
            @{{mendingCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" id="washCost" name="washCost" v-model.number="washCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="washCost_error">
            @{{washCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" id="pcqCost" name="pcqCost" v-model.number="pcqCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="pcqCost_error">
            @{{pcqCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="ironCost" name="ironCost" v-model.number="ironCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="ironCost_error">
            @{{ironCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="sewingCost" name="sewingCost" v-model.number="sewingCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="sewingCost_error">
            @{{sewingCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="packingCost" name="packingCost" v-model.number="packingCost"
               class="input-custom form-control"/>
        <div class="error" v-if="packingCost_error">
            @{{packingCost_error}}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="smvCostSum" class="">
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name=""
               class="input-custom form-control" v-model="knittingCostTTL"
               readonly/>

    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" v-model="linkingCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" v-model="tremingCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" v-model="mendingCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" v-model="washCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" v-model="pcqCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" v-model="ironCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" v-model="sewingCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" v-model="packingCostTTL"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"
               class="input-custom form-control" readonly/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" @click="saveSMVcost()">
            Save
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total Profit</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>%</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

**vue js code:**

```
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#smvcost",
        data: {
            order_id: '',
            order_option: '',
            selectOrderOptions: [],
            orderLcData: [],
            details_cost_breakdown: [],
            form: '',
            ifSelected: false,


            knittingTime: '',
            linkingTime: '',
            tremingTime: '',
            mendingTime: '',
            washTime: '',
            pcqTime: '',
            ironTime: '',
            sewingTime: '',
            packingTime: '',

            knittingCost: '',
            linkingCost: '',
            tremingCost: '',
            mendingCost: '',
            washCost: '',
            pcqCost: '',
            ironCost: '',
            sewingCost: '',
            packingCost: '',

            totalCostSum: '',

            knittingCost_error: '',
            linkingCost_error: '',
            tremingCost_error: '',
            mendingCost_error: '',
            washCost_error: '',
            pcqCost_error: '',
            ironCost_error: '',
            sewingCost_error: '',
            packingCost_error: '',


        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.getAllOrderForCost();
        },
        computed: {
            knittingCostTTL: function () {
                return this.knittingTime * this.knittingCost;
            },

            linkingCostTTL: function () {
                return this.linkingTime * this.linkingCost;
            },
            tremingCostTTL: function () {
                return this.tremingTime * this.tremingCost;
            },
            mendingCostTTL: function () {
                return this.mendingTime * this.mendingCost;
            },
            washCostTTL: function () {
                return this.washTime * this.washCost;
            },
            pcqCostTTL: function () {
                return this.pcqTime * this.pcqCost;
            },
            ironCostTTL: function () {
                return this.ironTime * this.ironCost;
            },
            sewingCostTTL: function () {
                return this.sewingTime * this.sewingCost;
            },
            packingCostTTL: function () {
                return this.packingTime * this.packingCost;

            },


        },


        methods: {


            saveSMVcost: function () {
                var base_url = window.location.origin;
                var page_url = base_url + '/bca/smv-cost-action';
                var form = document.querySelector("#smv-cost-form");
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                $('#ajax-call-effect').show();

                axios.post(page_url, formData).then(

                    function (response) {
                        console.log('Test');
                        $('#ajax-call-effect').hide();
                        if (response.data.errors) {
                            response.data.errors.knittingCost ? app.knittingCost_error = response.data.errors.knittingCost[0] : app.knittingCost_error = '';
                            response.data.errors.linkingCost ? app.linkingCost_error = response.data.errors.linkingCost[0] : app.linkingCost_error = '';
                            response.data.errors.tremingCost ? app.tremingCost_error = response.data.errors.tremingCost[0] : app.tremingCost_error = '';
                            response.data.errors.mendingCost ? app.mendingCost_error = response.data.errors.mendingCost[0] : app.mendingCost_error = '';
                            response.data.errors.washCost ? app.washCost_error = response.data.errors.washCost[0] : app.washCost_error = '';
                            response.data.errors.pcqCost ? app.pcqCost_error = response.data.errors.pcqCost[0] : app.pcqCost_error = '';
                            response.data.errors.ironCost ? app.ironCost_error = response.data.errors.ironCost[0] : app.ironCost_error = '';
                            response.data.errors.sewingCost ? app.sewingCost_error = response.data.errors.sewingCost[0] : app.sewingCost_error = '';                    

   response.data.errors.packingCost ? app.packingCost_error = response.data.errors.packingCost[0] : app.packingCost_error = '';
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Test');
                            /*$('#knittingCost').val('');
                            $('#linkingCost').val('');
                            $('#tremingCost').val('');
                            $('#mendingCost').val('');
                            $('#washCost').val('');
                            $('#pcqCost').val('');
                            $('#ironCost').val('');
                            $('#sewingCost').val('');
                            $('#packingCost').val('');*/
                            app.knittingCost_error = '';
                            app.linkingCost_error = '';
                            app.tremingCost_error = '';
                            app.mendingCost_error = '';
                            app.washCost_error = '';
                            app.pcqCost_error = '';
                            app.ironCost_error = '';
                            app.sewingCost_error = '';
                            app.packingCost_error = '';
                            app.showNotification('top', 'center', response.data.status, response.data.message);
                        }
                    })
            },

            showNotification: function (from, align, color, msg) {
                $.notify({
                    icon: "",
                    message: msg
                }, {
                    type: color,
                    placement: {
                        from: from,
                        align: align
                    },
                    delay: 2000,
                });
            },

            /*  totalCost: function () {
                  this.items.push({
                      parseInt(
                      this.knittingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.linkingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.mendingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.pcqCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.sewingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.ironCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.packingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.tremingCostTTL()) + parseIntthis.washCostTTL();
              })
                  /!*return parseInt(this.knittingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.linkingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.mendingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.pcqCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.sewingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.ironCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.packingCostTTL()) + parseInt(this.tremingCostTTL()) + parseIntthis.washCostTTL();*!/
              },*/

            getAllOrderForCost: function () {
                var base_url = window.location.origin;
                $('#ajax-call-effect').show();
                var page_url = base_url + '/bca/get-all-order-for-smv-cost-add';
                this.$http.get(page_url).then(
                    function (response) {
                        app.selectOrderOptions = response.data;
                        $('#ajax-call-effect').hide();
                    }
                );
            },

            changeTableData: function (order_option) {
                var order_id = order_option;
                var base_url = window.location.origin;
                var page_url = base_url + '/bca/get-buyer-info-for-cost-break-down/' + order_id;
                this.$http.get(page_url).then(
                    function (response) {
                        app.orderLcData = response.data;
                        app.ifSelected = true;
                        Vue.nextTick(function () {
                            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
                        })
                    }
                );

            },

            detailsCostBreakDown: function (order_id) {
                var base_url = window.location.origin;
                $('#ajax-call-effect').show();
                var page_url = base_url + '/bca/get-details-cost-break-down/' + order_id;
                this.$http.get(page_url).then(
                    function (response) {
                        app.details_cost_breakdown = response.data.costBreakdown;
                        $('#ajax-call-effect').hide();
                    }
                );
            },

            convertDate: function (date) {
                return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
            },

            /* ----------------------
           / Total Calculation
           /  ------------------------
           */
            sumOrderQty: function () {
                var total = 0;
                this.details_cost_breakdown.forEach(function (input) {
                    total += Number(input.qty);
                });
                return total.toFixed(2);
            },

            totalLcValue: function () {
                var total = 0;
                this.details_cost_breakdown.forEach(function (input) {
                    total += Number(input.qty * input.unit_price);
                });
                return total.toFixed(2);
            },

            totalYarnQty: function () {
                var totalYarn = 0;
                var yarnWastage = 0;
                this.details_cost_breakdown.forEach(function (input) {
                    totalYarn += Number(input.yarn_qty);
                    yarnWastage += Number(input.wastage_yarn);
                });
                var total = totalYarn + yarnWastage
                return total.toFixed(2);
            },

        }
    })
;
Vue.directive('tooltip', function (el, binding) {
    $(el).tooltip({
        title: binding.value,
        placement: binding.arg,
        trigger: 'hover'
    })
})
```

Comment: where you made your screenshot, click on the network tab, then find the 500 request and screenshot the response contents

Comment: What did you find in the preview section as @Erubiel suggested ?

Comment: or look at the storage/logs/laravel.log file to see the error !